# Access values from previous step using Formik Wizard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I'm creating a multi step form using [Formik's Wizard component](https://github.com/formium/formik/blob/master/examples/MultistepWizard.js). I can't figure out how to access values from the previous `<WizardStep />`. So for instance, In step 1 there are fields for `firstName` and `lastName`. Is it possible to read those values in the second step?

All the values are printed in the second step `onSubmit` but how can I access them in the actual `<WizardStep />` component?

Basically how to pass props to next `<WizardStep />`

[Codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-brook-orpto)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ErrorMessage, Field, Form, Formik } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { Debug } from './Debug';

const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

// Wizard is a single Formik instance whose children are each page of the
// multi-step form. The form is submitted on each forward transition (can only
// progress with valid input), whereas a backwards step is allowed with
// incomplete data. A snapshot of form state is used as initialValues after each
// transition. Each page has an optional submit handler, and the top-level
// submit is called when the final page is submitted.
const Wizard = ({ children, initialValues, onSubmit }) => {
  const [stepNumber, setStepNumber] = useState(0);
  const steps = React.Children.toArray(children);
  const [snapshot, setSnapshot] = useState(initialValues);

  const step = steps[stepNumber];
  const totalSteps = steps.length;
  const isLastStep = stepNumber === totalSteps - 1;

  const next = values => {
    setSnapshot(values);
    setStepNumber(Math.min(stepNumber + 1, totalSteps - 1));
  };

  const previous = values => {
    setSnapshot(values);
    setStepNumber(Math.max(stepNumber - 1, 0));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (values, bag) => {
    if (step.props.onSubmit) {
      await step.props.onSubmit(values, bag);
    }
    if (isLastStep) {
      return onSubmit(values, bag);
    } else {
      bag.setTouched({});
      next(values);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={snapshot}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      validationSchema={step.props.validationSchema}
    >
      {formik => (
        <Form>
          <p>
            Step {stepNumber + 1} of {totalSteps}
          </p>
          {step}
          <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
            {stepNumber > 0 && (
              <button onClick={() => previous(formik.values)} type="button">
                Back
              </button>
            )}
            <div>
              <button disabled={formik.isSubmitting} type="submit">
                {isLastStep ? 'Submit' : 'Next'}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <Debug />
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

const WizardStep = ({ children }) => children;

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Formik Multistep Wizard</h1>
    <Wizard
      initialValues={{
        email: '',
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
      }}
      onSubmit={async values =>
        sleep(300).then(() => console.log('Wizard submit', values))
      }
    >
      <WizardStep
        onSubmit={() => console.log('Step1 onSubmit')}
        validationSchema={Yup.object({
          firstName: Yup.string().required('required'),
          lastName: Yup.string().required('required'),
        })}
      >
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
          <Field
            autoComplete="given-name"
            component="input"
            id="firstName"
            name="firstName"
            placeholder="First Name"
            type="text"
          />
          <ErrorMessage className="error" component="div" name="firstName" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
          <Field
            autoComplete="family-name"
            component="input"
            id="lastName"
            name="lastName"
            placeholder="Last Name"
            type="text"
          />
          <ErrorMessage className="error" component="div" name="lastName" />
        </div>
      </WizardStep>
      <WizardStep
        onSubmit={() => console.log('Step2 onSubmit')}
        validationSchema={Yup.object({
          email: Yup.string()
            .email('Invalid email address')
            .required('required'),
        })}
      >
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <Field
            autoComplete="email"
            component="input"
            id="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Email"
            type="text"
          />
          <ErrorMessage className="error" component="div" name="email" />
        </div>
      </WizardStep>
    </Wizard>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use React context or Redux for this purpose. Here's how to do it with React Context.

Step1: Create a "provider" which will be a state container for all of your wizard steps. It's very simple and it contains a single state.

```
const WizardContext = createContext();

const WizardProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [wizardState, setWizardState] = useState({});

  const value = useMemo(() => [wizardState, setWizardState], [
    wizardState,
    setWizardState
  ]);

  return (
    <WizardContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</WizardContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useWizardContext = () => useContext(WizardContext);
```

Step 2: Fix your `App` component and wrap its content in the provider:

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Formik Multistep Wizard</h1>
    <WizardProvider>
      <AppContainer />
    </WizardProvider>
  </div>
);
```

Step 3: Use the wizard context in the following way. Basically, control the global state via `setWizardState` function and access to it via `wizardState`.

```
const AppContainer = () => {
  const [wizardState, setWizardState] = useWizardContext();
  
  return (
    <Wizard .....>
      <WizardStep onSubmit={(values) => {
          setWizardState(values);
          console.log("Step1 onSubmit");
        }}></WizardStep>
      <WizardStep onSubmit={() => {
          console.log(wizardState);
          console.log("Step2 onSubmit");
        }}>
        <div>{wizardState.firstName}</div>
      </WizardStep>
    </Wizard>
  )
}
```

Here's a full working Code Sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-galois-8xxwd?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just what I was looking for. Any idea how to get access to formik props like `setFieldValue` inside the steps?

Comment: @DJ2 You can experiment by "pushing" the whole formik to the provider's state. I also strongly recommend switching to the latest Formik since you can use it as a hook which eases up control over the whole formik object (no need for refs).

Comment: Are you referring to `useFormikContext()` or `useFormik()`?

Comment: `useFormik` hook.

Comment: I updated the sandbox you posted to try and implement `useFormik()` 
<https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-grass-guq0o?file=/src/App.js> Am I on the right track here?

Comment: Correct! That looks good. Basically, you bind the JSX to `formik`.

Comment: hmmm I'm trying to wrap the `<Wizard ../>` component with the new provider but `formik` is undefined. I see that you cannot use `<Field />` , etc with `useFormik()` because it requires react context.

Comment: I've implemented this and can successfully access the values from a previous page after submitted. However, I am looking to control one select element based on another from the same page. Is it possible to access values from the same page prior to submit?